# How to send Batch messaging in yii using Clickatell SMS gateway

Tags: php, batch-file, yii

Am using Yii Framework. single and group sent SMS now working fine. but
now I want to sent Batch messaging using Clickatell.

This is single SMS API's link

Yii::app()->sms->send(array('to'=>'407xxxxxxxx', 'message'=>'Hello world!'));

how to send Batch messaging?

pls help me.-:)

Answer (score 0):

```
$messages = array();
$messages[] = array('to'=>'0001000','message'=>'Hello');
$messages[] = array('to'=>'0002000','message'=>'Hello');
foreach($messages as $message){
    Yii::app()->sms->send(array('to'=>$message['to'], 'message'=>$message['message']));
}
```

Same message to all

```
$message = "Hello world!";
$to = array();
$to[] = '001000';
$to[] = '200100';
foreach($to as $number){
    Yii::app()->sms->send(array('to'=>$number, 'message'=>$message));
}
```

Comment: I want to send single sms to 1000 person with in one script(script want to execute one time only) like that i want script code.

Comment: In your code script ll be execute every person(contacts). ex. 2 times your code will be executed..

Comment: Yes. I don't know how clicatell gateway or your class works so this is solution that absolutely sure works

Comment: Command: 
http://api.clickatell.com/http_batch/startbatch?session_id=xxx&...............&template=Hi #field1#, your balance 
is #field2#.&from=Sender&deliv_ack=1

Comment: Is it a problem to call the function multiple times ? I read clickatells http api documentation and could't find any other way

Comment: Format the message with php directly. That way it's not a problem. Like I said I don't have your php library so I can't help much more